# How can i the get the http response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

when I import class

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

as per https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

it gives error Target URL doesn't exist

Comment: Can you share your complete code logic where you are making http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the http package to your dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file and call flutter packages get

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
  http: 0.12.0+2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the http package

> ```
> import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
> ```

2. Make a network request

> ```
> Future<http.Response> fetchPost() {
>   return http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
> }
> ```

In the above example target url is

> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Corresponding response is

> ```
> {
> "userId": 1,
> "id": 1,
> "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
> "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
> }
> ```

More details available in

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data